Are there any Linux GUI applications that can generate / export cue sheets?
I'm looking for an application -- or perhaps a plugin to something like Audacity -- that would allow a user to place cue point marks graphically, and then generate and export a filename.cue cue sheet file with indices pointing to the times where the marks were placed.
My use case: When trying to learn a piece by ear, 't'would be nice to loop measures and phrases that don't have convenient names like "intro" or "verse" or "chorus". Looking at a waveform can often show a logical point to add a loop point when there's a frame of silence or some other indicator. An external file that does not mess with the original audio would seem ideal.
So, while I could manually construct something from repeated listening together with trial and error, a graphical approach would be quite useful, methinks.

Audacity has a feature called Labels. Try that.
